# Utility methods for operating on custom scala class

Tags: scala, oop, abstract-class

I'd like to define an operator that works on a custom class in Scala.  Similar to scala's [Array utility methods](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$), such as Array concatenation:

```
val (a, b) = (new Array[Int](4), new Array[Int](3))
val c = Array.concat(a, b)
```

I'd like to define an operator vaguely as follows:

```
class MyClass {
  def op():MyClass = {
     // for instance,, 
     return new MyClass();
  }
}
```

to be invoked, like 
`val x = MyClass.op()`

To provide a more concrete example, suppose that MyClass is an extension of MyAbstractClass

```
// Provided as a utility for the more relevant code below. 
def randomBoolean():Boolean = {
  val randomInt = Math.round(Math.random()).toInt
  if (randomInt == 1 ) return true;
  else return false;
}

abstract class MyAbstractClass[T](size:Int) {
  val stuff = new Array[T](size)
  def randomClassStuff():Array[T]
}

class MyClass(size:Int) extends MyAbstractClass[Boolean](size) {
  def randomClassStuff():Array[Boolean] = {
    return new Array[Boolean](size) map {x => randomBoolean()}
  } 
}
```

I realize that I could define an object called MyClass with a function called randomClassStuff defined in there, but I'd rather utilize abstract classes to **require that extensions of the abstract class provide a method that creates random stuff specific to that class**.

Comment: 1. I'm confused. What is the question?

Comment: 2. The three code examples all seem to be very different, and not really analogous to each other at all.

Comment: 3. Your last sentence describes exactly what you did.

Comment: I'll assume you mean you want the functionality of the third snippet, with the syntax of the second one? See my answer

Comment: I gave you the syntax of the first with the combined functionality of the third and second. The last two lines of my answer look like your first two lines.

Comment: I guess the subtlety that I neglected to flesh out is the fact that operator has no arguments, specifically that it does not have as an argument an instance of MyClass. Rather, it is a function that generates a random instance of MyClass.

Comment: Then why are you calling it an operator? And what is wrong with the just using a companion object?

Comment: Maybe operator was the wrong choice of word. I guess I meant "class-specific function". The reason using a companion object doesn't suit my needs is that I'd like it to be required that a descendent class has such a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your first example, to be able to invoke an operator `concat` as `Array.concat()`, there needs to exist an object called `Array` somewhere in scope that has `concat` as a method. The simplest way to do that would be:

```
object Array {
  def concat[T](xs: Array[T], ys: Array[T]): Array[T] = ...
}
```

Otherwise you could define an abstract class (or trait) and have the object inherit it:

```
abstract class ArrayUtils {
  // Implemented here
  def concat[T](xs: Array[T], ys: Array[T]): Array[T] = ...
}

//Define the object
object Arrays extends ArrayUtils

// Or as a val
val Array = new ArrayUtils {}
```

Alternatively the abstract class could just define the operator and the object would implement it:

```
abstract class ArrayUtils {
  // Defined here
  def concat[T](xs: Array[T], ys: Array[T]): Array[T]
}

object Arrays extends ArrayUtils {
  // Implemented here
  def concat[T](xs: Array[T], ys: Array[T]): Array[T] = ...
}
```

The last is probably closest to what you wanted.

Comment: This answers the question as stated.  I ended up implementing it slightly differently, in a different abstract class that defined a collection of the original class, similarly to your first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We can define an OpTrait that declares a method ("op") that operates on something of the same type, so that any class that implements that method can only take in arguments of the same type as the class it was declared in.

Then, we can define an object that takes any two objects of the same type, as long as they include the "op" method (by mixing in the OpTrait--you can alternatively use structural typing, but that's slow and less organized):

```
trait OpTrait[B] {
    def op(b: B)
}

object MyClass {
    def op[A <: OpTrait[A]](x: A, y: A) = x.op(y) // x op y
}
```

Now we can create any class that extends OpTrait and class MyClass.op(obj1, obj2):

```
// example of usage
class MyClass(val num: Int) extends OpTrait[MyClass] {
    def op(b: MyClass) = new MyClass(num + b.num)
}

val (a,b) = (new MyClass(5), new MyClass(6))
MyClass.op(a, b) // should return MyClass(11)
```

Since the OpTrait is parameterized on a generic type, you can actually define an operation between different types (but only in one order). You can also define the operation to work on MyClass and a subtype of MyClass by making it covariant, but only when arguments are in one order.